Induced map in a cartesian square is a monomorphism
Consider the following cartesian square composed of four monomorphisms.


The induced map from the pushout $Y\coprod Z$ to $T$ is also a monomorphism.

Why is it the case? the pushout of a mono is a mono, so $Z\to Y\coprod Z$ and $Y\to Y\coprod Z$ are also mono. Is it enough to say that  $Y\coprod Z \to T$ is a mono?
Thanks for any help or reference.

What do you mean  by "cartesian square"? My answer below assumes you just mean commutative square.

@RobArthan a cartesian square is a pullback square.

This condition is not generally true; see https://mathoverflow.net/questions/437194/in-which-categories-is-the-union-of-subobjects-given-by-the-pushout-over-the-int for some sufficient conditions for a category to satisfy this. This property (or something closely related) seems to go by the name "effective unions" in the literature.

Is @NaïmFavier right about you wanting the square to be a pullback square? In all the usual motivating examples of categories, the projections of a pullback square won't be monomorphisms except in the trivial case where both $Y$ and $Z$ are terminal objects.

@RobArthan monomorphisms are stable under pullback so if the bottom-right two maps are mono then all four are mono. This situation is of interest when asking whether the poset of subobjects of $T$ has binary joins/unions (see the linked answer).

Note: the below assumes the OP means "commutative square" not "cartesian square". As noted in the comments, it would be very odd to make the conjecture of the question for pullback squares.
This is (easily seen to be) true in any concrete category where the underlying set of a pushout is the same as the pushout of the underlying sets. It is not true in general. Assume you are working in the category of groups and take $X = 1$, $Y = Z = T = G$, where $G$ is any non-trivial group, and take the morphisms at the right and the bottom both to be $I_G$ (there is only one possibility for the left and top morphisms). Then $X \coprod Y$ is the free product $G * G$ of $G$ with itself, but the morphism $G * G \to T$ arising from the universal property of the pushout is not a monomorphism (since if $g \in G \setminus \{1\}$ and $\iota_L, \iota_R : G \to G * G$ are the left and right injections, then $\iota_L(g) \neq \iota_R(g)$, but the morphism to $T$ identifies them).

That's not a pullback square, is it?

No, but the question doesn't seem to be about pullback squares (and if it were, you wouldn't expect the top and left morphisms to be monic except in trivial examples). That said, I realise now that the OP talks about "cartesian square" and I don't know what is meant by that. I've added a comment asking for clarification.

@NaïmFavier: apologies. I forgot to point my response to your comment in your direction.
